# Angular - Using *ngIf with *ngFor to specific rows in table

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I'm pretty new to Angular and I'm trying to make a pipe to filter items out of my table and am not quite sure how to go about that. I'm trying to only display the table fields where the EmpKey = empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here's my tracker.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-12':isHidden === true, 'col-xs-7': isHidden !== false}">
    <button class="form-control" style="width:150px;" (click)="toggleSummary()">Open Summary</button>
    <select id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Employee Name...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{i}} - {{emp.EmpID}}</option>
    </select>
    <select id="PTOtype">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Type of PTO...</option>
      <option value="PTO">PTO</option>
      <option value="ETO-Earned">ETO - Earned</option>
      <option value="ETO-Used">ETO - Used</option>
      <option value="STDLTD">STD/LTD</option>
      <option value="Uncharged">Uncharged</option>
    </select>
    <button class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" (click)="nextEmployee()">Next</button>
    <button class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" (click)="previousEmployee()">Previous</button>
    <h2 *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">{{empInfo[selectedEmployee].FirstName}} {{empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey}}</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Full/Half</th>
          <th>Hours</th>
          <th>Scheduled?</th>
          <th>Notes</th>
          <th>In P/R?</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let pto of ptoData>
          <td>{{pto.date | date: 'MM/dd/y'}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.EmpKey}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.fullhalf}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.hours}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.scheduled}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.notes}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.inPR}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isHidden" class="col-xs-5">
        <pto-summary [selectedEmployee]="selectedEmployee"></pto-summary>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's my tracker.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-tracker',
    templateUrl: `./tracker.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    ptoData: PTOData[];
    isHidden: boolean = false;
    public selectedEmployee: number;

    constructor(
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService,
        private ptoDataService: PTODataService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
            );
    }

    getPTOData(): void {
        this.ptoDataService.getPTODatas().then(
            ptoData => this.ptoData = ptoData
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
        this.getPTOData();
    }

    toggleSummary(): void {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }

    nextEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee+1;
    }

    previousEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee-1;
    }
}
```

Thanks again!

**EDIT for Clarification** - The user will select an employee from a dropdown list which will give me the index of the employee that was chosen. from there, I want to filter out the results that don't contain that EmpKey by using the value from empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey. In the table, there are many different EmpKeys and whenever a user is selected, I only want the fields that share that EmpKey to be printed out and change to another employees whenever a different one is selected.

Comment: The code above only selects one employee at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to create a directive for that :

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let pto of ptoData">
       <tr *ngIf="condition" >
          <td>{{pto.date | date: 'MM/dd/y'}}</td>
          ...
       </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

Now a row will only display if `condition`.

---

So your code becomes

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let pto of ptoData">
       <tr *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey" >
          <td>{{pto.date | date: 'MM/dd/y'}}</td>
          ...
       </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear enough. The user will select an employee from a dropdown list which will give me the index of the employee that was chosen. from there, I want to filter out the results that don't contain that EmpKey. There will be many different EmpKey's selected

Comment: @rcarc what prevents you from doing that with my code ? I think I'm missing something

Comment: Whenever I used the code that you gave, it just always prints out the entire table and nothing changes whenever I select different employees from the combo box.

Comment: @rcarc what is the condition  you put in there ?

Comment: *ngIf="pto.EmpKey = empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey." Thinking about it again, I don't believe that would work, but I'm not quite sure what I'd put here.

Comment: @rarc actually it should work as well like you did. The issue is that you are using `=` instead of `===`

Comment: the thing is, I need the selectedEmployee field for another component so I need the [ngValue] to equal i and I can't change that

Comment: @rcarc ok then use the condition you posted above and replace = by === (notifce I switched ngFor with ngIf in the code..

Comment: that would work if the EmpKey was the same as the index of the employee in the array. so the value that i'd need is empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey, which doesn't work. I'm almost 100% sure that I need to use a pipe to filter it

Comment: @rcarc I assure you it's how you are supposed to do it. `that would work if the EmpKey was the same as the index of the employee in the array.` No because you are doing this: `pto.EmpKey = empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey`.

Comment: @rarc want to go in the chat ?

Comment: okay, I got it to work. sorry for the confusion, I just had to initialize my selectedEmployee field to 0